# How to add a class in a method - VUE.js

Tags: class, vue.js, methods, click

Basic question but still I cannot figure out how to add an extra class based on @click. I still get error: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"

```
methods: {
    hideItems() {

        document.getElementsByClassName('sold').classList.add('hide')
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` return `HTMLCollection` so you need to loop through that collection.

that should do it:

```
methods: {
    hideItems() {
        const items = document.getElementsByClassName('sold');

        for(item of items){
           item.classList.add('hide');
         }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `:class="{ hide: hidden }"` property on your element, where `hidden` is a boolean property of the Vue component. This will toggle the `hide` class on the element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      hidden: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.hidden = !this.hidden;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle">
  Toggle visibility
  </button>
  <div :class="{ hide: hidden }">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the correct answer